# Issue with Core Module: Unable to Import and Use "Corerect"

Tags: python

I am facing a problam while trying to import and use the "Corerect" module in my Python project. I have installed the module using pip, but whenever I try to import it, I recieve an error message stating that the module doesn't exist. I have also verifyed that the module is listed in my installed packages.

I have already tryed reinstalling the module and even upgrade my Python version, but the problam persists. I couldn't find much documentation or references regarding this issue.

Could anyone provide insight into why I am unable to import and utilize the "Corerect" module in my project? Is there something I'm missing or any additional steps required for using this module successfuly?

Any help or guidanse would be greatly appriciated. Thank you in advance!

I have already tried reinstalling Python version, but the problem persists. I couldn't find much documentation or references regarding this issue.

Comment: Probably, you have multiple pythons installed and you are installing the package to one particular instance which isn't the one that you are running your code with